# users.list returns 403 Error: Not Authorized to access this resource/api

Tags: node.js, google-admin-sdk, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to retrieve a list of users using the node.js googleapis library and a service account.

I followed [this guide](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) to 'Perform Google Apps Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority'. There are examples for Java and Python, but unfortunately not for node.js, which seems to work rather differently.

I tried following the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/nodejs) and completed the first two steps, but then it uses a manual OAuth flow instead of a service account.

So I tried to follow the example [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#using-api-keys) to authorize using a service account. That all seems to work until I send the request, then I get an error: `Error: Not Authorized to access this resource/api` with code: 403.

Here's my code:

```
var google = require('googleapis'),
   GoogleAuth = require('google-auth-library'),
   authFactory = new GoogleAuth(),
   admin = google.admin('directory_v1')

authFactory.getApplicationDefault(function (err, authClient) {
      console.log('GOT APPLICATION DEFAULT', authClient)
      if (err) {
        console.log('Authentication failed because of ', err);
        return;
      }
      if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
        console.log('SCOPE REQUIRED')
        var scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'];
        authClient = authClient.createScoped(scopes);
      }

      var request = {
        auth: authClient,
        domain: 'mydomain.com'
      };
      console.log('request:', request)
      admin.users.list(request, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('admin.users.list error', err);
        } else {
          console.log(result);
        }
      });
    });
```

What have I missed please?

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of experimenting I came to the conclusion that this particular API cannot be accessed with a service account. Although it is not explicitly stated in the docs anywhere that I could find, the quickstart seems to overcome this limitation by using an OAuth process and then storing in a file the tokens required to authorize future requests. If I'm wrong please add a better answer!

My solution is to use the quickstart project to generate those tokens and then add the credentials and tokens from the quickstart to my project and use them whenever my server starts, something like:

```
let tokens = require('./credentials/tokens.json'),
    credentials = require('./credentials/oauth_credentials.json'),
    clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret, 
    clientId = credentials.installed.client_id,
    redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0],
    google = require('googleapis'),
    GoogleAuth = require('google-auth-library'),
    authFactory = new GoogleAuth(),
    admin = google.admin('directory_v1'),
    oauth2Client = new authFactory.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);
    oauth2Client.credentials = tokens;
    let request = {
      auth: oauth2Client,
      domain: 'coachaxis.com'
    };
    console.log('request:', request)
    admin.users.list(request, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('admin.users.list error', err);
      } else {
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
```

It's not elegant but it works.

Comment: I was able to get a user list with a service account, but I think you always have to use an OAuth process to get an access token.  There is a lot of setup on Google's side of things that has to happen correctly before your token will work right, including but not limited to: allowing the scope in your service account (in the Admin console, Security section), using some kind of Admin account as a "sub" that has access to read users.